# Automatically create entries in database table (php/mysql)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, database

I am working on a project which keeps a record of lets say amount of money spent in a day.
Lets say the beginning day(first entry) in the database is 1-Jan-2013. 
Now everyday I will submit an entry to the database but on some days I cant. The table looks like this:

Date_***_*__*_*_**|__*_*___Spent

2013-01-09 | 2000

2013-01-11 | 1200

Lets suppose today is 11-jan-2012 and I forgot to make an entry on 10-jan-2012. Now I want to write the code using php+mysql, which will go through the table and check if there are any dates missing between the first entry and the latest entry. And when it finds that the entry for the day 10-jan-2012 is missing, it should create the entry itself with amount 0 in the spent column. How can I achieve this? Is there any better approach then the one I am trying to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way to accomplish this is to `JOIN` on a table that has a full calendar or make a table of dates. You could write a cursor, but it's considered a last resort.

Comment: This is the best approach. If you try to rely on cron jobs, you have to also handle the case where the cron job fails to run (for any reason). If you build a table of dates, you can be sure you've got it right.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try this and get back to you immediately when I have the results

Comment: I came up with this **[CODE](http://pastebin.com/pnwUr6n1)**.  

It would help me a great deal if you could let me know if its an acceptable approach and wont have any future problems.

Answer (score 1):

here is my suggestion,create one file that will store the last date of the script run,suppose today(2013-01-11) you have run that script than it will store simply 2013-01-11 in that file,if you run it again tomorrow it will store tomorrow's date 2013-01-12.

we will use this date to create query and reduce our processing time.

date stored in file is our $minDate,

find out max date from db using query say it is $maxDate,

query:Select Date,Spent from table Where date('Date')>$minDate;

Store result in a array $dateArray

create one date array using period between $minDate and $maxDate

```
$starting_date = new DateTime($minDate." 00:00");
$ending_date = new DateTime($maxDate." 23:59:59");


$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new  DatePeriod($starting_date , $interval, $ending_date);
foreach ($period as $date) {
  $curDate=$date->format('Y-m-d');
  if(!in_array($curDate,$dateArray)){
     //insert new row with $curDate
  }
}
update lastProcessedDate in your file
```

Comment: I was thinking of the exact same thing and wrote this **[CODE](http://pastebin.com/pnwUr6n1)**.  

Do let me know if its good and wont have any future problems.

Comment: @user1688606 yep,both are same and it will not have any problem,just you have forgot to update lastProcessedDate in your code,i also forgot to mention it here

Comment: I guess I have updated the lastProcessedDate. you can see it on the last line of the code

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure and schedule it to run nightly.  Something like create cursor to loop through the table, order by the Date column, then check the previous record to see how many days are missing, if more than 1, insert individually.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this like this: Create a cronjob which runs your PHP script in the early morning hours (say 2am or so).
The script will take the current date minus 1 (yesterday) and use a select query to the database. If it does not find an entry, it will create one.
When you have it running every day, you will make sure, that there is always an entry of yesterday.